# Server side rendering - vite + reactjs + express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vite, server-side-rendering

I am trying to server side render my vite + react application. I followed vite documentation to create the server and now everything seems to run correctly. I am new to server side rendering so I have some doubts. When i see my page source when the app initially renders, it is showing the correct page source as expected. But if I interacts with my app and loads another view, the page source is not updated. Is this the normal behaviour, or is there anything i can do to get the updated page source whenever I change my view from the client side.

This is my server.js

```
import fs from "node:fs/promises";
import express from "express";

global.window = {};

// Constants
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const port = process.env.PORT || 5173;
const base = process.env.BASE || "/";

// Cached production assets
const templateHtml = isProduction
  ? await fs.readFile("./dist/client/index.html", "utf-8")
  : "";
const ssrManifest = isProduction
  ? await fs.readFile("./dist/client/.vite/ssr-manifest.json", "utf-8")
  : undefined;

// Create http server
const app = express();

// Add Vite or respective production middlewares
let vite;
if (!isProduction) {
  const { createServer } = await import("vite");
  vite = await createServer({
    server: { middlewareMode: true },
    appType: "custom",
    base,
  });
  app.use(vite.middlewares);
} else {
  const compression = (await import("compression")).default;
  const sirv = (await import("sirv")).default;
  app.use(compression());
  app.use(base, sirv("./dist/client", { extensions: [] }));
}

// Serve HTML
app.use("*", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const url = req.originalUrl.replace(base, "");

    let template;
    let render;
    if (!isProduction) {
      // Always read fresh template in development
      template = await fs.readFile("./index.html", "utf-8");
      template = await vite.transformIndexHtml(url, template);
      render = (await vite.ssrLoadModule("/src/entry-server.tsx")).render;
    } else {
      template = templateHtml;
      render = (await import("./dist/server/entry-server.js")).render;
    }

    const rendered = await render(url, ssrManifest);

    const html = template
      .replace(`<!--app-head-->`, rendered.head ?? "")
      .replace(`<!--app-html-->`, rendered.html ?? "");

    res.status(200).set({ "Content-Type": "text/html" }).end(html);
  } catch (e) {
    vite?.ssrFixStacktrace(e);
    console.log(e.stack);
    res.status(500).end(e.stack);
  }
});

// Start http server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

My vite.config is as follows

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import viteTsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
// import macrosPlugin from 'vite-plugin-babel-macros'
import svgrPlugin from "vite-plugin-svgr";
// import path from 'path'
import { splitVendorChunkPlugin } from "vite";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
// How to migrate from CRA to vite: https://cathalmacdonnacha.com/migrating-from-create-react-app-cra-to-vite

import dns from "dns";

dns.setDefaultResultOrder("verbatim");

export default defineConfig({
  define: {
    "process.env": {},
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        find: "stream",
        replacement: `stream-browserify`,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    react({
      babel: {
        presets: ["@babel/preset-typescript"],
        plugins: [
          "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript",
          [
            "babel-plugin-styled-components",
            {
              ssr: false,
              pure: true,
              displayName: true,
              fileName: false,
              minify: false,
              transpileTemplateLiterals: false,
            },
          ],
        ],
      },
    }),
    viteTsconfigPaths(),
    svgrPlugin(),
    splitVendorChunkPlugin(),
  ],
  build: {
    outDir: "build",
    cssCodeSplit: false,
  },
  ssr: {
    noExternal: ["styled-components", "@emotion/*"],
    // noExternal: [],
  },
  server: {
    open: true,
    port: 5173,
  },
  preview: {
    port: 8000,
  },
});
```

My entry-client.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "@store/index";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.hydrateRoot(
  document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement,
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

My entry-server.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "@store/index";
import App from "./App";

export function render() {
  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );
  return { html };
}
```

Comment: _"Interact"_ how?

Comment: For example, when the app loads, it shows the home page as it is the starting point of the app. when i see the page source, everything is ok. it has the content of the home page. But if i click on a button and loads a separate view (not a new route, but a new view from the same route), I want my page source to have the content of new view.

Comment: You'll need to [edit] your question to provide details but in general, if you're using a SPA router (like react-router-dom), it won't perform full page loads if you use its `<Link>` components